# IntelliJ not using local maven downloaded artifact

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Why does IntelliJ attempt to download an artifact which is already in my local Maven repository every time I attempt to build or run a solution?

For each test run, I get the following line in the output window:

```
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: org/forgerock/forgerock-parent/1.2.1/forgerock-parent-1.2.1.pom
```

I have selected the option:

```
Use plugin registry
```

Within the Maven Settings window in (View -> Tools Window -> Maven) but this did not help.

Comment: Does it help if you enable offline mode?

Comment: Do you have any `repositories` defined with a custom update policy? Do you have `Always update snapshots` checked in the IJ Maven config or are you running your build with `-U`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the standard behaviour of Maven.

As @Morfic already indicated, there are two main places to look:

- Your Maven build is started with the parameter `-U` (in Eclipse, this can also be set as `UpdateSnapshot` policy for a build). Then every POM is downloaded again.
- Your `settings.xml`, which defines the repositories, has an entry for the given repository that overwrites the update policy (beware that repositories are sometimes set in the POM as well).